# How to calculate percentages for categorical variables by items?

Tags: r, percentage, summarization

I have a question about calculating the percentage by items and time bins. The experiment is like this:

I conduct an eye-tracking experiment. Participants were asked to describe pictures consisting of two areas of interest（AOIs; I name them `Agent` and `Patient`). Their eye movements (fixations on the two AOIs) were recorded along the time when they plan their formulation. I worked out a dataset included time information and AOIs as below (The whole time from the picture onset was divided into separate time bins, each time bin 40 ms).

```
Stimulus   Participant    AOIs         time_bin     
1          M1             agent          1               
1          M1             patient        2               
1          M1             patient        3               
1          M1             agent          4               

...
1          M2             agent          1               
1          M2             agent          2               
1          M2             agent          3              
1          M2             patient        4               
...
1          M3             agent          1               
1          M3             agent          2               
1          M3             agent          3              
1          M3             patient        4
...

2          M1             agent          1               
2          M1             agent          2               
2          M1             patient        3              
2          M1             patient        4
```

I would like to create a table containing the proportion of one AOI (e.g. agent) by each stimulus of each time bin. It would be like this:

```
Stimulus      time_bin      percentage     
1                1            20%              
1                2            40%               
1                3            55%               
1                4            60%    
...
2                1            30%              
2                2            35%               
2                3            40%               
2                4            45%
```

I calculate the percentage because I want to do a multilevel analysis (Growth Curve Analysis) investigating the relationship between the dependent variable `agent fixation proportion` and the independent variable `time_bin`, as well as with the `stimulus` as a random effect.

I hope I get my question understood, due to my limited English knowledge.

If you have an idea or a suggestion, that would be a great help！

Comment: Can you change the `%` observations in your desired output to be actual percentages, so it's easier to understand what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your edition and advice heds1!!! I have already changed those values.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how you arrived at your particular percentages. Could you explain how `20%` and `40%` etc. are calculated? From your data, I would have assumed the first row (`Stimulus == 1`, `time_bin == 1`) would have an `agent` percentage of `100%`, since the AOI is always `agent` in the example data you have given.

Comment: Sorry! I should answer it with more details. I included the data of other participants that I did not list in the example data. I would correct and re-edit it. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse` package ecosystem you could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(percentage = as.integer(AOIs == "agent") ) %>%
  group_by(Stimulus, time_bin) %>%
  summarise(percentage = mean(percentage))
```

Note that this will give you ratios in the `[0, 1]` interval. You still have to convert it to the percentage values by multiplying with 100 and appending "%".

Comment: Use `as.integer(AOIs == "agent")` instead of `if_else`, it's faster. Upvote.